# Import Excel file in to Python as a list

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I want to import one column with 10 rows in to Python as a list.

So I have in excel for example: One, Two, Three, Four,..., Ten
Everything written in column A over row 1-10.

Now I want to import these cells into Python, so that my result is:

```
list = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', ..., 'Ten']
```

Since I am a total noob in programming, I have no clue how to do it. So please tell me the most easiest way. All tutorials I have found, did't got me the result I want. 
Thank you

I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Easiest way is to use `pandas`. Highlight the column entries and copy. Then use `l  = pd.to_clipboard().values` Note that you will need a title for your column to make it work really easily. Also don't assign variables to `list` this will prevent you from using the function `list(stuff)`

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately I get an Attribute Error back: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_clipboard'

I  also tried it with 
'df = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx', sheetname='Tabelle1')'
but then I get a DataFrame and not a list.

Comment: Sorry its read_clipboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure if your data is in xlsx form or CSV form. If XLSX, use [this Python Excel tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-excel-tutorial). If CSV, it is much easier, and you can follow the code snippet below. If you don't want to use pandas, you can use the `numpy`library. Use the example code snippet below for taking the top row of a CSV file:

```
import numpy as np
csv_file = np.genfromtxt('filepath/relative/to/your/script.csv', 
                          delimiter=',', dtype=str)
top_row = csv_file[:].tolist()
```

This will work for a file that has only one column of text. If you have more columns, use the following snippet to just get the first column. The '0' indicates the first column.

```
top_row = csv_file[:,0].tolist()
```

Answer (score 4):

Even though [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is a great library, for your simple task you can just use [xlrd](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/):

```
import xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path_to_my_workbook)
ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
mylist = ws.col_values(0)
```

Note that `list` is not a good name for a variable in Python, because that is the name of a built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing pandas.

```
pip install pandas
```

and

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_excel('path/to/data.xlsx') # The options of that method are quite neat; Stores to a pandas.DataFrame object
print df.head() # show a preview of the loaded data
idx_of_column = 5-1 # in case the column of interest is the 5th in Excel
print list(df.iloc[:,idx_of_column]) # access via index
print list(df.loc[['my_row_1','my_row_2'],['my_column_1','my_column_2']]) # access certain elements via row and column names
print list(df['my_column_1']) # straight forward access via column name
```

(checkout [pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html))
or

```
pip install xlrd
```

code

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
wb = open_workbook('simple.xls')
for s in wb.sheets():
  print 'Sheet:',s.name
  for row in range(s.nrows):
    values = []
    for col in range(s.ncols):
       values.append(s.cell(row,col).value)
    print ','.join(values)
```

(example from https://github.com/python-excel/tutorial/raw/master/python-excel.pdf)